# How do I format an array of objects by iteration in Model in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I want to format an array of objects to send a substitution data in a Model. I would like to format that by iterating through a data called, "bags" and it's also an array of objects.
For example,

```
bags = [{id: 1, name: "name1", product_id: 1}, {id: 2, name: "name2", product_id: 2"}]
```

The data "bags" has a relationship with "product" model so each bag has one product.
I know I can get the "product" data by doing:

```
bags.map{|bag| bag.package}
```

However, I'm confused on how to use the result and re-format it as an array of object, since the result comes as an array.

I want to iterate through "bags" and use its relationship to get the "product" data to create an array of objects like this:

```
bag: 
   [
    {bag_name: "name1", product_name: "product1"}, 
    {bag_name: "name2", product_name: "product2"}
   ]
```

Please let me know if you need further information.

Comment: Please show us the model files, (Bag? Product?) and their associations (has_many, has_one, belongs_to etc). This will help to clarify your question. BTW in Ruby this construct: {id: 1, name: "name1"} is called a hash, not an object, objects are something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from what I'm understanding, you are trying to map bags into an array of object for each bag. Here is how I'd probably do with the information you've given:

```
bags.map do |bag|
  {bag_name: bag[:name], product_name: bag.package}
end
```

In this function, `bag[:name]` return the name properties of each bag, whereas `bag.package` returns the product "data" you mentioned. It map through the `bags` array and output an array of objects using `map` method.

Feel free to give it a try and update here if there's any further errors/problems.

Cheers :)

Comment: Thank you @Kyle-Law It worked perfecto! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: It's fulfilling to solve your problem @hl010! It'd be great if you could leave an upvote on this post by clicking the ^ button. :)